# how to install devtoolset-8 / GCC 8 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: gcc, amazon-linux, devtoolset

On an Amazon Linux 2 Docker image, "yum install gcc" installs gcc 7.3.1.

I want to install gcc 8. It seems it normally can be installed as part of "devtoolset-8" (https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/), but the instructions for either CentOS or RHEL seems not working on Amazon Linux.

So the only way to install gcc 8 on Amazon Linux is to install from source?

I also need the devtoolset-8-toolchain, how can that be installed?

Answer (score 12):

Add the scl repo for centos:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/
```

Install this libgfortran dependency required for devtoolset-8:([source](http://yuminstall.org/how-to-install-libgfortran5-8-3-1-2-1-1-el7-x86_64-on-centos7/))

```
sudo yum install -y wget
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libgfortran5-8.3.1-2.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install libgfortran5-8.3.1-2.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm -y
```

Install devtoolset-8 with nogpgcheck:(it would be much better to install the key for the repo)

```
sudo yum install -y devtoolset-8 --nogpgcheck
```

Finally enable the scl for devtoolset-8:

```
scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
```

Running this command shows both the gcc 7 and gcc 8 in the path:

```
which -a gcc
```

Output from `which -a gcc`

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```